# Display data from database in a dropdown in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have one table, categories where I have name of category and ID. I have to create a form where I need to show a dropdown box which has a list of categories from table. As I am a beginner in ruby on rails, I dont know how to do that. Please help.
Here's my _from.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@xyz) do |f| %>
  <% if @xyz.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@xyz.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this xyz from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @xyz.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <select>
    <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@category.categories, "id", "categ_name") %>
    </select>
    </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avatar %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried using this <%=optin%> thing but I am having error.
this is my model

```
class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => 'video/mp4'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this:

```
<select>
    <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@categorey.categoriesl, "id", "categ_name") %>
</select>
```

To

```
<%= select_tag "categories", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "id", "categ_name") %>
```

This will generate the whole tag for you with an `id` of "categories" which you should probably change so it nests correctly in params

Not sure what `@category.categories` looks like it is not referenced anywhere in your post though if it's an array then use

```
<%= select_tag "categories", options_for_select(Categorey.scoped.pluck(:name)) %>
```

Comment: I thought @category is my model and categories is my table name. I am not sure though because I copied this line from somewhere else. It would be a great help if you tell me how to access table's data

Comment: @categorey is an instance variable and should be assigned in your controller. Categorey uppercase is the model associated with the database table categories. To acess these it would be. Category.all or Categorey.scoped see my updated answer.